# How to insert image into div using form and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

Is it possible to insert an image from my computer into a div using a jquery and html FORM element ?

I make something like this to insert text nodes into div:

HTML

```
<form>
  <div><input type="text"  id="text" ></div>
  <div><input type="button" value="Add" onclick="append()" /></div>
</form>
```

Javascript

```
function append() {
  var value = $('#text').val();
  $('#rightcolumn').append('<p>'+value+'</p>');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't specify anything about the div in your sample code, but just assuming that the div has the id "rightcolumn," then you could insert an image in the same way that you are inserting the p element:

```
$("#rightcolumn").append("img").prop("src", "my_image_file.jpg");
```

This assumes that my_image_file.jpg is on the same compute and in the same directory as the web page itself. If that is not the case, then specify the full URL to the image file on your computer for the src property.

---

**Update**

To get the local URL for the image, assuming that the HTML is being accessed through a `file` URL and not through an `http` URL, you could something like the following.

Add an input field of type file to your form:

```
<label for="img_input">Select an image file:</label>
<input id="img_input" name="img_input" type="file" />
```

Add this code to your `append` function:

```
var imgUrl = $("img_input").val();
$("#rightcolumn").append("img").prop("src", imgUrl);
```

Note that this approach will *only* work cross-browser if you have opened the web page from the local file system and not through a web server (even a local web server). For security reasons, most browsers will not allow a web page that came from a web server to get the full path of local file name. If you opened the web page from an http URL, then `$("img_input").val()` will typically return only the file name, not the full path.

I am not aware of any reliable, cross-browser technique to the full path of a local file from a web page loaded from a web server.

Comment: Ok, but how can I do this with input form ? How to specify a path to image without typing it directly as a parameter in .prop method ?

Comment: I am sorry, It doesn`t work. When I do console.log(imgUrl); in firebug it outputs: C:\fakepath\myfile.png

Comment: When you got the "C:\fakepath..." result, was the page loaded with a URI that begins with "file://"? I would expect the "fakepath" result with a URI that begins with "http://" or "https://".

Answer (score 1):

You will usually need to upload the image to a server in order to view the image in your page. There are some browsers that will support what you want without uploading using constructs from html5 but uploading is probably your best bet for now.

Answer (score 1):

use this jquery TO GET iMAGE URL FROM TEXTBOX:

```
$("#YourBtnToshowImageID").click(function () {
    var imgurl=($("#YourImageUrlTextBox").val());
$("#YourDivUrl").append("img").prop("src", imgurl);

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Place a `<div>` inside your page and set its `id` to something unique such as `targetdivid`
Save `imageurl` as a JavaScript array such as `imageurls`

Finally apply the following technique

```
$.each(imageurls,function(i,url){$("<img/>").attr("src",url).appendTo("#targetdivid")});
```